# Postgresql 9.2 pg_dump version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to dump a Postgresql database using the **pg_dump** tool.

```
$ pg_dump books > books.out
```

How ever i am getting this error.

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.2.1; pg_dump version: 9.1.6
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

The `--ignore-version` option is now deprecated and really would not be a a solution to my issue even if it had worked.

How can I upgrade **pg_dump** to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can either install PostgreSQL 9.2.1 in the `pg_dump` client machine or just copy the `$PGHOME` from the PostgreSQL server machine to the client machine. Note that there is no need to `initdb` a new cluster in the client machine.

After you have finished installing the 9.2.1 software, remember to edit some environment variables in your `.bash_profile` file.

Answer (score 115):

1. Check the installed version(s) of pg_dump:

   ```
   find / -name pg_dump -type f 2>/dev/null
   ```
2. My output was:

   ```
   /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_dump
   /usr/bin/pg_dump
   ```
3. There are two versions installed. To update pg_dump with the newer version:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump --force
   ```

This will create the symlink to the newer version.

Comment: It was much quicker for me  to find the versions using ```locate pg_dump```

Comment: IMO, you should not add `2>/dev/null` since that will throw out the ERROR stream rather than printing it to the console. I think one should want to see any errors happening, except some rare cases. For example, in my case, it reminds me that I was not root thus failing to see some directories where the newer pg_dump version was installed. In general, don't remove errors.

Answer (score 94):

I encountered this while using Heroku on Ubuntu, and here's how I fixed it:

1. Add the PostgreSQL apt repository as described at "[Linux downloads (Ubuntu)](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)
   ". (There are similar pages for other operating systems.)
2. Upgrade to the latest version (9.3 for me) with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install postgresql
   ```
3. Recreate the symbolic link in `/usr/bin` with:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump --force
   ```

   The version number in the `/usr/lib/postgresql/...` path above should match the `server version` number in the error you received. So if your error says, `pg_dump: server version: 9.9`, then link to `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.9/...`.

Comment: This only happens when you upgrade PostgreSQL. I just did a fresh install of the OS and didn't have any problems with this.

Comment: For anyone wondering, this solution applies to non-Heroku Ubuntu as well.

Comment: According to what has been said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836312/postgresql-9-2-pg-dump-version-mismatch/16130071#16130071), it's a pretty bad idea as well.

Comment: That answer recommends removing software by deleting a folder. Here we're just recreating a symbolic link.

Comment: Perfect! Recreating the symbolic link after postgres upgrade

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I never imagined that the version mismatch was caused by /usr/bin/pg_dump which has nothing to do with my fresh PostgreSQL update. I'm fine with the ln solution.

Comment: I'm using centos and by doing yum postgresql I get that I have the latest postgresql version installed. And I still get that error :( So it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @VaTo see the additional paragraph I added to the 3rd step.

Comment: @VaTo what is the full text of your error? Since you're on CentOS, replace that path with the path to your installation of PostgreSQL.

Comment: I had to get a pg_dump newer version from another machine and then copy that pg_dump file into this machine and now it works.

Answer (score 45):

Macs have a builtin `/usr/bin/pg_dump` command that is used as default.

With the postgresql install you get another binary at `/Library/PostgreSQL/<version>/bin/pg_dump`

Comment: Location will vary depending on how PostgreSQL was installed (EnterpriseDB installer, MacPorts, Homebrew, etc), but the gist of the answer - that the user probably has the right version already installed - is certainly right.

Comment: In my case, opening .bash_profile and adding "export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/contents/macos/bin:$PATH" did the magic.

Answer (score 44):

You can just locate `pg_dump` and use the full path in command

```
locate pg_dump

/usr/bin/pg_dump
/usr/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dump
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_dump
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_dumpall
```

Now just use the path of the desired version in the command

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_dump books > books.out
```

Comment: For CentOS users (my version is 6.9 Final): `sudo /usr/pgsql-<version>/bin/pg_dump <database-name> -U <username> -h localhost`

Comment: @jDub9 what version did you use while taking the dump? Make sure you are using the same

Comment: The first time it needs `sudo updatedb` to create the locate db

Comment: Clean solution.  I had had postgres 13 and 14 installed, and just needed to point it to 14/bin/pg_dump.  Problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 25):

If you have docker installed you can do something like:

```
$ docker run postgres:9.2 pg_dump books > books.out
```

That will download the Docker container with Postgres 9.2 in it, run `pg_dump` inside of the container, and write the output.

Comment: This is by far the simplest and most flexible solution.

Comment: This command was useful in my case: `docker run --net host --rm -i postgres:14.1 pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres dbname > pg.dump.schema.sql`

Comment: Here's a function to add to your `.bashrc`: `pg_dump-version() { docker run --rm "postgres:${1}-alpine" pg_dump ${@:2} }` ­—  e.g. `pg_dump 14 $PG`

Answer (score 19):

If you're on Ubuntu, you might have an old version of `postgresql-client` installed.  Based on the versions in your error message, the solution would be the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-client-9.1
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-9.2
```

Answer (score 15):

On Ubuntu you can simply [add the most recent Apt repository](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) and then run:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-11
```

Answer (score 12):

Every time you upgrade or re install a new version of PostgreSQL, a latest version of  `pg_dump`   is installed.

There must be  a  `PostgreSQL/bin`   directory somewhere on your system, under the latest version of PostgreSQL that you've installed ( 9.2.1 is latest) and try running the 
 `pg_dump`  from in there.

Comment: Tip: in `Terminal.app`, `find / -name pg_dump -type f 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 12):

For those running **Postgres.app**:

1. Add the following code to your `.bash_profile`:

   ```sh
   export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH
   ```
2. Restart terminal.

Comment: This worked just fine!

Comment: For those using newer Macs (with Zsh instead of Bash), place the above in your `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 10):

For Macs with Homebrew. I had this problem when fetching the db from Heroku. I've fixed it just running:

```
brew upgrade postgresql
```

Comment: You can sometimes (easily) get particular versions from it too do `brew search postgres` to see them all.

Answer (score 7):

For mac users
put to the top of .profile file.

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

then run

```
. ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative answer that I don't think anyone else has covered.

If you have multiple PG clusters installed (as I do), then you can view those using `pg_lsclusters`.

You should be able to see the version and cluster from the list displayed.

From there, you can then do this:

```
pg_dump --cluster=9.6/main books > books.out
```

Obviously, replace the version and cluster name with the appropriate one for your circumstances from what is returned by `pg_lsclusters` separating the version and cluster with a /. This targets the specific cluster you wish to run against.

Comment: This is very useful. As I was confused why `pg_dump` was not working on one of my clusters. Turns out, it was using default Postgresql version, when one of my clusters was upgraded to newer version. Specifying cluster, solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

For me the issue was updating `psql` `apt-get` wasn't resolving newer versions, even after `update`. The following worked.

**Ubuntu**

Start with the import of the GPG key for PostgreSQL packages.

```
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now add the repository to your system.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: This won't replace the existing executable files on your computer, so you'll need to explicitly use the new version of pg_dump, e.g. /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_dump or make a new shortcut e.g. /usr/bin/pg_dump96

Comment: I didn't have to explicitly use the new it picked it up.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me, a collection of solutions from above and other sites. If you specified a version like postgressql-client-11 before then you need to remove that version first.

```
sudo apt-get remove -y postgresql-client
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-client-12
```

Answer (score 4):

As explained, this is because your postgresql is in old version -> update it
For Mac via homebrew:

`brew tap petere/postgresql`,

`brew install <formula>` (eg: `brew install petere/postgresql/postgresql-9.6`)

Remove old postgre:

`brew unlink postgresql`

`brew link -f postgresql-9.6`

If any error happen, don't forget to read and follow brew instruction in each step.

Check this out for more: https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql

Answer (score 4):

I had same error and this is how I solved it in my case. 
This means your postgresql version is 9.2.1 but you have started postgresql service of 9.1.6.

If you run `psql postgres` you will see:

`psql (9.2.1, server 9.1.6)`

What I did to solve this problem is:

1. `brew services stop postgresql@9.1.6`
2. `brew services restart postgresql@9.2.1`

Now run `psql postgres` and you should have: `psql (9.2.1)`

You can also run `brew services list` to see the status of your postgres.

Answer (score 3):

The answer sounds silly but if you get the above error and wanna run the pg_dump for earlier version go to bin directory of postgres and type

./pg_dump servername > out.sql  ./ ignores the root and looks for pg_dump in current directory

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue. I used docker instead of upgrading pg_dump.

run following command to create a Docker container of postgres 14.2, or any other [version](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) as you like.

```
sudo docker run --name mac_postgres -p 5444:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres:14.2
```

Then take dump using following command. Note: you should change the *host*, *port*, *username* and *password* according to your actual database credentials.

```
sudo docker exec -it  mac_postgres  pg_dump --host=xxxxx0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com --port=250xx --username=doadmin --dbname=test --password > out.sql
```

After entering password. Your dump will be ready in **out.sql** file. Then you can delete the docker-container.

```
sudo docker stop mac_postgres
sudo docker rm mac_postgres
```

Comment: You should have docker installed on your system to proceed with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Heroku's Postgres.app the pg_dump (along with all the other binaries) is in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/`

so in that case it's

`ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_dump /usr/local/bin/pg_dump`

or

`ln -s /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/* /usr/local/bin/.`

to just grab them all

Answer (score 2):

** after install postgres version is match(9.2)
Create a symbolic link or new shortcut

**- on '/usr/bin'

```
syntag is = sudo ln -s [path for use] [new shortcut name]
```

example

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_dump new_pg_dump
```

-- how to call : new_pg_dump -h 192.168.9.88 -U postgres database

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

If the database is installed on a different machine it has probably correct version of pg_dump installed. This means that you can execute pg_dump command remotely with SSH:
   `ssh username@dbserver pg_dump books > books.out`

You can also use public key authentication for passwordless execution. Steps to achieve that:

1. Generate (if not yet done) a pair of keys with ssh-keygen command.
2. Copy the public key to the database server, usually  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.
3. Test if the connection works with ssh command.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the same issue as I have two postgress versions installed.

Just use the proper pg_dump and you don't need to change anything, in your case:

```
 $> /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_dump books > books.out
```

Answer (score 1):

For macs, use `find / -name pg_dump -type f 2>/dev/null` find the location of pg_dump

For me, I have following results:

```
Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_dump
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/bin/pg_dump
```

If you don't want to use `sudo ln -s new_pg_dump old_pg_dump --force`, just use:

`Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_dump` to replace with `pg_dump` in your terminal

For example:

```
Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.5/bin/pg_dump books > books.out
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 1):

On my scenario the production version was 12, and my development version was 11, upgrading the package `postgresql-client-xx` was enough to solve my incident.

Reference web page : https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade postgresql-client
```

One interest thing to point out is that after the upgrade the previous version kept installed :

```
mlazo@mlazo-pc:~$ dpkg -l |grep -i postgresql-client
ii  postgresql-client-11                                             11.8-1.pgdg18.04+1                                  amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 11
ii  postgresql-client-12                                             12.4-1.pgdg18.04+1                                  amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 12
```

Hope my experience would be helpful to someone.

Greetings,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message, for me it was that I had to adjust the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/pgsql-12/lib:....
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/pgsql-12/lib:.....
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: see if postgres has a repository with prebuilt binaries for the version you want for your OS: https://www.postgresql.org/download/

If that doesn't work (for instance if your distro is there but is no longer supported, so correct binaries aren't provided for it), or if you just want to go straight or the source and not have to worry about adding remote repo's, etc.

What I did is [download](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/) the raw source of postgres for the desired version.

Untar it, cd into it, build it `./configure && make`, then:

```
postgresql-12.3 $ find . -name pg_dump
./src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump
$ ./src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump


unable to load libpg.so.5 # if it says this...
$ find . -name libpg.so.5
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/path/to/the/shared/dir/of/above/file

$ ./src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump # works now
```

Now you have access to any version that builds on your box.  Which should be any.

Answer (score 0):

#### Full steps tutorial

Your local version needs to match the one used by AWS on the remote server.
Unfortunately, apt-get install will lag behind the official release.

So you need to proceed the following way:

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then check your error message should be something like

```
pg_dump: server version: 12.3; pg_dump version: 10.16 (Ubuntu 10.16-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

**So it means you want version 12 (and not 13), for the install of the matching version by specifying the version number (without minor) during your fresh install:**

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-12
```

Now it works:

```
pg_dump -h {{endpoint}} -U {{username}} -f dump.sql {{tablename}}
```

**NB: You get the endpoint in **Connectivity & security** go to https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-east-2 and click on your DB instance**

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in the **yaml file**. You need to **install the image version you need** by indicating which version of postgres you need. The code sample below specify to install postgres 15 rather than the latest which currently is 16. For you case, it should be 9.1.6

```
services:
    source_postgres:
    image: postgres:15
    ports:
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu 20.04 with the "official" postgresql repo, moving from pg12 to pg13, I had to do this:

```
sudo apt purge postgresql-12
```

This was very hard for me to pinpoint.  I had played with a variety of these packages:

- postgresql-client
- postgresql-client-common
- postgresql-##
- postgresql-client-##
- postgresql-server-dev-##
- pgadmin

Answer (score -2):

```
run pg_dump -d [DATABASE] -h [HOST] -p [PORT] -U [USER]
```

it matches pg_dump with postgres version and runs your dump successfully

Answer (score -6):

I experienced a similar problem on my Fedora 17 installation. This is what I did to get around the issue

- Delete the builtin `pg_dump` at `/usr/bin/pg_dump` (as root: "rm /usr/bin/pg_dump")
- Now make a symbolic link of the postgresql installation

  Again as root `ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump`

That should do the trick

Comment: Nonono, don't just delete package managed files! If it's in `/usr/` (rather than `/usr/local/`, `/home/` or `/opt/`, where deleting things is generally OK) you *really* need to use the package manager - `rpm` & `yum` or `dpkg` and `apt-get` or `aptitude`, distro-depending. Either uninstall the package with `rpm` or alter your `PATH` environment variable in your `.bash_profile` so that the newer version is found first. If you're in doubt about something being under package management, use `rpm -qf /path/to/file` (RPM) or `dpkg -S /path/to/file` (dpkg)

Comment: Agreed, but at least my package manager, apt in Ubuntu 20.04 using the "official" postgres repo, leaves this bad /usr/bin/pg_dump link from an old install and will not refresh it no matter what I ask it to do (and I asked it to do a LOT before giving up).