# Conflict with Server Version of PostgreSQL 9.2.1 and pg_dump Version 9.1.4 (Rails 3.2.9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql, pgadmin

I recently did a clean install of Lion Server on my Mac Mini Server then immediately upgraded to Mountain Lion without copying any of my data from my backup files.  Then I reinstalled my Rails applications and deployed them to production (same machine).  I also took my PgAdmin backup file that I created under Lion Server and rebuilt my database using it after upgrading to Mountain Lion.

When I go into the PostgreSQL terminal I get the following message.  The basic commands I am using this for work without any problems.

```
psql (9.1.4, server 9.2.1)
WARNING: psql version 9.1, server version 9.2.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.
```

I also had problems with implementing the queue_classic gem in my Rails application because it said that the server version of psql is 9.2.1 but pg_dump is version 9.1.4.

psql --version produces psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.4

pg_dump --version produces pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.1.4

I was using gem pg 0.12.2 in my Rails application.  Now I am using version 0.14.1.  The problem began after I upgraded to Mountain Lion while still using version 0.12.2.  When I rebuilt my Rails app the databases were createdby  hand in PgAdmin.  I did rake db:migrate to rebuild the table structures and indices.  I then used my PgAdmin tar backup file to rebuild the data.

I attempted to install the latest stable version of phpPgAdmin.  I had a problem because there was a missing column in PostgreSQL.  The documentation from PostgreSQL stated that the column was removed in version 9.2.  At this point I determined that the database was 9.2.1.  I also assumed at the time that was the version that Mountain Lion had installed.  I was wrong in that assumption.

I then reinstalled PgAdmin for database maintenance in order to restore my databases using my backup.  When I check the properties on the database used in my Rails app it says it is a PostgreSQL 9.2.1 database.

These are the only software packages that I have installed relating to PostgreSQL at all.  I have not installed another version of PostgreSQL on my machine unless somehow one of these packages did something that I was not aware of.

I do not use Homebrew, MacPorts or any similar tools.  I may at some point.

When I do a Finder search for psql in /usr I only find one file in /usr/bin.  My guess that is the one that is version 9.1.4.

All the research that I have read about this is regarding people that have installed another version of PostgreSQL themselves.  This may sound really dumb but how on earth can I create a database with a higher version of PostgreSQL than is currently installed?  This is apparently what happened when I rebuilt my database from my backups even though I did not specify a version.  How can I fix this problem?  I would like to use version 9.2.1 since I believe that is the latest stable version of PostgreSQL.  I am very open to suggestions.  I just need my database to somehow match the version of PostgreSQL I am using so I will not be impeded in using gems or other PostgreSQL processes that check the version of psql and pg_dump.  I guess I have two options, either install PostgreSQL 9.2.1 somehow or recreate my database under 9.1.4.  I just wonder about having two versions of PostgreSQL installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because there is no guarantee that the dump will include everything given new features in a new version.  In fact due to possible changes in system catalogs, one cannot guarantee it will work at all, so the tools typically generate warnings, but pg_dump will fail.  You should be able to dump the data manually.  So other tools like the Ruby gems may be more cautious about how they handle the warning.

However, if you installed PostgreSQL 9.2.1, I would also expect that you should have all the related client tools too.  You may be able to resolve this by simply searching your system for pg_dump and psql and seeing if you can locate new versions (you may have both installed at once).  It sounds however like you did this, but see [Postgresql 9.2 pg_dump version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836312/postgresql-9-2-pg-dump-version-mismatch) which has some mac-specific answers which suggests the version you want to use is not in /usr.

The next step really be to look at how PostgreSQL was installed and look for reasons you might be missing the tools.