# pg_dump: sever version:11.7; pg_dump version: 10.3(Ubuntu-10.3-1) pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch

Tags: postgresql, backup, pgadmin-4, pg-dump

I use `pip3 install pgadmin4==4.30` to install `pgadmin` in my `ubuntu`. And I want to backup my remote server data by Tools-Backup in `pgadmin`, which is equal to the following command.

```
/usr/bin/pg_dump --file "~/demo.backup" --host "127.0.0.1" --port "42885" --username "postgres"....
```

However there is an error says:`pg_dump: sever version:11.7; pg_dump version: 10.3(Ubuntu-10.3-1)`. One thing that puzzles me is I don't have `version 11.7` installed at all. Here is the output of `ls -la /usr/bin/pg_dump`

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Mar 2 18:05 /usr/bin/pg_dump -> /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_dump
```

And there is only one version(`10`) in `/usr/lib/postgresql` folder. Anyone can tell me how I can fix this? I have tried every solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836312/postgresql-9-2-pg-dump-version-mismatch) and neither of them worked out.

Comment: You do have PostgreSQL 10.3 installed on the machine where you run pgAdmin, and pgAdmin uses the `pg_dump` executable from that installation. Upgrade the PostgreSQL client.

Comment: It is the remote server that has 11.7 installed.

Comment: Are it actually using `pgAdmin` to do this or are you running it from the command line? How are you dumping a remote server using `--host "127.0.0.1"`? Is there forwarding going on? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  I use it in `pgadmin`, the command is `pgadmin` shows.

Comment: You have not answered all the questions, nor have you done as requested  and updated your question with the latest information. So you are using the Tools --> Backup in `pgAdmin`, correct? Update you question with the information.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yeah, that is quite right. I use Tools --> Backup in `pgadmin`. I have edited my question.

Comment: You still have not answered how you are dumping a remote server via `127.0.0.1`? Or where the remote server is and what Postgres version it is?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks Adrian Klaver, I think that is the point. I have tested a remote server which is not `127.0.0.1` which works well.

Comment: Bottom line is what ever Postgres server you are trying to dump from is version 11.7 and the `pg_dump` is coming from a Postgres 10.3 install. As the error states that will not work. `pg_dump` is backwards compatible, but can not dump from newer version then it's own. Until you provide a consistent and complete explanation of what you are doing this is as much as I can offer.